# pass checkbox values from child form to parent form upon submit using javascript

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have the below code in a coldfusion parent form. ON click of a checkbox a child window (abc.cfm) opens which has for example 5 checkboxes related to the check box on the parent window.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="inq" id="inq" value="#item_code#"     onClick="window.open('abc.cfm?inq=#item_code#');">#item_description#  
 <span class="style6">Click the checkbox for the list</span>
```

User checks 1 or more check boxes on the child window and hits submit on the abc.cfm page; the child page will close and The values selected need to be displayed on the parent.cfm page. Can anyone please let me know how to go about this.

This is on my parent cfm page.

```
  <td colspan="2"  class="trr3"><textarea cols="30" rows="5"  name="narr"></textarea>    </td>
  <td width="32" valign="top"  class="trr3">Brief</td>
  <td width="499" valign="top"  class="trr3"><input type="text" name="brief" size="30"></td>
```

I have the below code on the child abc.cfm page.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

 function figure_this_out(){
   var boxes = document.form1.cat;
    var display = "";
     var t = document.getElementById("category_id").value;
    for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++){
    if (boxes[i].checked == true){
   display = display + boxes[i].value + ", ";
   t = display;
  //alert(t);
  window.opener.document.getElementById("category_id").value=t;
  window.opener.document.getElementById("narr").value =          document.getElementById("narr").value;
 window.opener.document.getElementById("brief").value =                    document.getElementById("brief").value;
       }
         }
        window.close();
            } 
             </script>

       <table>
      <cfloop query="nature_compl"> 
         <cfif nature_compl.currentrow mod 3 EQ 1>      
        <tr>
     </cfif>
    <td class="trr3">

    <input type="checkbox" id="cat" name="cat" value="#category_id#"   onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.category_id.value=this.value; else    this.form.category_id.value=''" >
     #category_description#

     </td>
        </cfloop>

         <input  type="hidden" name="category_id" id="category_id"   value="">
        <tr>
     </td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="trr3">
Brief &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="brief" size="38">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="trr3">
Narrative
<textarea cols="30" rows="5"  name="narr"></textarea>
</td>

</tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="button" class="groovybutton2" value="SUBMIT" name="save"   onClick="figure_this_out();" > 

     </td>

  <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: So are you gettings errors?  what is happening?

Comment: Iam able to pass the brief and narrative to the parent page. I need to be able to pass the category description which have been selected to the parent page. Pls advice. I getting the catergory_id on the parent page. But i need to be able to catch the category descrition.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your not assigning the category Description to an object that javascript can reference.  try putting it in a div with an ID.

Comment: I added a div with same id on the parent (placed empty div) and child page(placed category description in the div), and added window.opener.document.getElementById("catdesc").value = document.getElementById("catdesc").value; to the JS function. It is still not working can u please guide me? thanks

Comment: To reference the Div internals its innerHTML, i believe